# Managed Service Provider on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-iam

If a Managed Service Provider (MSP) wants to monitor existing GCP projects of a client that are associated to a client billing account ( meaning the client is directly paying to Google for it ) , how can the MSP start monitoring those ? What are the strategies around IAM that enable the MSP to start monitoring the client projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview)(Identity and Access Management), any member can be assigned with the access/control over the GCP resources/projects. You can check [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) documentation for various roles that can be given to a member.

For your specific concern over 'monitoring the billing', a member (in your case a MSP provider) can be given any specific role under “[Cloud Billing Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud_billing_roles)”. It will help that member to view/manage various billing scenarios over the GCP project/resources.

Apart from your use case scenario, you can also check [this](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/12/expanding-our-partner-ecosystem-with-managed-services-providers.html) blog for various updates over [MSP partners](https://cloud.google.com/partners/). You can make valuable suggestion by commenting there as well.